# API endpoint resolvers for MVC4 .Net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web app that is making Web API calls to another server. In all of my controller methods right now I am hard-coding the URL of the API. I want to avoid this by building a resolver that translates a route to its API URL. Is there a pattern/framework in MVC4 that allows me to do this, or is this something I should just manually build?

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {

        public object Get(int id)
        {
            User u = WebApiCaller.GetWebApiResponse<User>
              ("http://localhost:50909/api/Users/1",
              WebApiCaller.HttpMethod.Get);
            return u;
        }

}
```

Comment: Where is the external API located? Is it on the same host? Is it always in the same place or is it dynamic? Are there multiple external  services you are calling? Are they user selectable or can the decision be made at development or deployment time? More detail please.

Comment: The API is in an another server, but in development, they will be in the same host. The endpoints are not dynamic.